# Two Routers, Different Internet connections, Same LAN, internal network redirection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-bridge

I setup two routers using different internet connections to be in the same LAN.

But I want to disable the WIFI in the second one and reroute all the torrent-traffic (or traffic on some particular ports) of the first router's wifi to the second one's internet connection. Is there a way to do this. Port forwarding did no help for me.

Requirement:

[image]

My major concern here is to reduce the load on bandwidth for the first internet connection which has a cap on data.

Comment: What routers are you using?

Answer (score -1):

I have a similar situation, the way that I have configured it is to have the a number of clients configured to use the second router as the default gateway.

So normally all clients take a DHCP gateway of the main router, but then some are configured (either manually or DHCP if you have Openwrt etc) to use the second router. So if there is one machine that you generally torrent from, you could direct that through the second router.

It is possible to split traffic based on type, destination etc, but that is considerably more complicated. but this answer should start you along the right line - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101505/route-traffic-out-different-gateway-by-destination-network